# Sonarqube Maven Error Not inside a git tree

Tags: java, git, maven, sonarqube

edit: somebody in the comment told me the question is not clear enough so i'm gonna edit my question.
So i'm trying to run sonarqube with my project i try to follow the instruction from the website(although maybe i miss something) there is error but i managed to fix some(error in repositories and stuff), after creating token and stuff in sonarqube local server i try to run the command they gave me but its always have this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project ad1treasury-api: Not
 inside a Git work tree: D:\my_kom\api -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:son
ar (default-cli) on project ad1treasury-api: Not inside a Git work tree: D:\my_kom\api
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Not inside a Git work tree: D:\backup\JF\Revamp JF\ad1treasury-api
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute (ScannerBootstrapper.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute (SonarQubeMojo.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.MessageException: Not inside a Git work tree: D:\backup\JF\Revamp JF\ad1treasury-api
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

i try to search online for the fix its seem that its project base directory being different than intended in the setting which is odd as the base dir that console said is correct only working dir is different

```
[INFO] Project key: Revamp_JF
[INFO] Base dir: D:\my_kom\api
[INFO] Working dir: D:\my_kom\api\target\sonar
```

i try to setting basedir in pom.xml as instructed on sonar website but its still not working please help me find a solution for this
this is the properties file to edit project basedir

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
        <sonar.projectBaseDir>D:\my_kom\api</sonar.projectBaseDir>
    <!-- <java.version>1.8</java.version> -->
</properties>
```

Note: this is not a git work so there is not git file maybe thats a problem?

Update: For more information this project is an api project, when i try to analyze the Interface part which is on the same folder it actually work. Still no luck with this api Project
here is the folder hierarchy

```
source
   I
   I
   I
   I ------>api
   I------->ui
```

Comment: Please try to describe exactly what you are doing and what is going wrong, including exact error messages and the exact inputs you are providing, and the exact outputs. Think about what information someone else would need to see when they know nothing about your problem.

Comment: ah alright i would edit my question thank you

Comment: @DavidM.Karr i already edit my question.please help me if you could

Comment: Try using the `sonar.sources` Property while running SonarQube analysis. Command to run: `mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.sources=**/*`

Comment: @SouravAtta thank you for the comment. i did run what you said unfortunately still didn't work. is sonar dependent on github/lab/or any git for that matter? because if it is that mean i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very specific. You have to be inside a git work tree, preferably at the root of it.  I have no idea where that is in this structure.

Comment: so sonar is dependent on gitlab/hub or any kind of git then?

Comment: i already did. Their problem is fixed when they add either sonar.projectBaseDir Or sonar.Source which didn't work for me the problem still persist